# Searching through large dataset in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, search, bloom-filter

I am developing a Rails application. I have a large dataset of static titles (about 3.5M) that I am searching a lot through. For now the dataset stored in my PostgreSQL db and I am searching using postgres' index and `text_pattern_ops`. This works pretty fast, but I am worried it might not scale, as my searches count supposed to increase rapidly.

I thought of storing my dataset in memory as an array and use bloom filtes/aho-coarsick to search, but not sure how or if it's a good approach.

Basically, I am searching for a fast and scalable way to search in large dataset with Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Is it structured data that you can parse out of the files and move into a database of some kind?

Comment: It is already stored in Postgres, I was just thinking if it's scalable to keep it in Postgres (considering that searches count is growing) or should I use a different approach

Comment: You're asking us to recommend tools, or give opinions, both of which are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You might find your question is more on-topic on http://dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

We use ElasticSearch, which integrates well with ruby on rails. http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/unleash-the-clients-ruby-python-php-perl/#ruby